# In Angular UI Grid - how to select and unselect rows on mouse drag over

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

For my requirement i need to select multiple values on mouse drag over and need to uncheck that on anti-directional drag. Is this feasible in UI Grid?

The desired result is similar to dragging a selection in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please read the help section on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I tried select and drag and its working but for reverse selection,unable to deselect all the items. That's why posted here and mine in a custom piece of code so unable to put share in plunker

Comment: Please read the articles in the link I provided.